# Django stopped running tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd

Hey, I have a problem similar to this one ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647227/django-test-runner-runs-0-tests)).

Approx 2 hours ago Django stopped running my tests. And I have no idea why. I did some refactoring, then got an ImportError and after I reverted the file, Django stopped running any of my tests. I already deleted all the *.pyc files but nothing changed.

***The situation:***
I organize all my tests in a sperate test-package. The structure is the following:

```
/app
  /tests
    /model
      __init__.py
      ...
    __init__.py
    ...
```

The `__init__.py` files define a `suite()` method that will return all the tests inside the packages like this:

```
def suite(): 
    suite = TestSuite()

    suite.addTest(model.suite())
    suite.addTest(user.suite())

    return suite
```

I tried to debug and set a breakpoint in the topmost `__init__.py` file in the test-package but this breakpoint is never reached.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha.. Now I found the error.

The problem was, that I ONLY thought I fixed all ImportErrors. When I started a shell using `manage.py shell` and then tried to import the tests-package I saw some other ImportErrors. Fixed them and now the tests are running again.

Wished the testrunner would have indicated that something went wrong!